How to create pivottable filter
How can i create a pivot table filter using python, like filter by "namecolumn1"" == 1 | 2. I've tried searching in the API documentation but idk how to do it.
I've tried everthing
if there is no method, it would be awesome to add a 'filters': in the API plsssss
